# How to add editable 'static' text on a Rails page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rubygems

I'm building a Rails weblog for a client, and he wants to have a site description he can edit. I'm not sure how to do it. In PHP I'd just save it to a separate table in the DB and save it on a column, and retrieve with a query, but my PHP times are far away.

How can this be done? Is there a gem or something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a model for it, and use it to persist the text to the database. If you somehow can attach it to an already existing model then it is even better.

Comment: yeah I think it's the best approach, I think I'll make a model for site info and store title, description and other things I might need

Comment: You can even expand it to a complex solution, and store the whole history of the fields, and even can dedicate a column to indicate which field it contains. This lets you to have a dynamic set of changable texts which can be expanded without database update.